# java subtype relationship

Tags: java, subtype

While reading [Horstmann's book](http://horstmann.com/design_and_patterns.html), I've encountered this about subtype relationship in Java:

```
S is a subtype of T if: 

S is an array type and T is Cloneable or Serializable
```

And I couldn't truly understand what this is supposed to mean. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like your not giving us all the information

Comment: Need a little more context

Comment: S and T are the same type

S and T are both class types, and T is a direct or indirect superclass of S

S is a class type, T is an interface type, and S or one of its superclasses implements T

S and T are both interface types, and T is a direct or indirect superinterface of S

S and T are both array types, and the component type of S is a subtype of the component type of T

S is not a primitive type and T is the type Object

S is the null type and T is not a primitive type


These are the other examples of the subtype relationship. Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of subtyping.

The `Array` type implements the `Cloneable` and `Serializable` interfaces.

However, these interfaces do not specify any methods as part of the method contract. In fact, these are only marker interfaces whose existence gives details to the compiler and users of your classes without directly requiring any functionality.

For example:

> Note that this interface does not contain the clone method. Therefore, it is not possible to clone an object merely by virtue of the fact that it implements this interface. Even if the clone method is invoked reflectively, there is no guarantee that it will succeed.

Comment: I am familiar with these interfaces. But, can I assign any array type to a class implementing Cloneable or Serializable, if there is a subtype relationship I should be able to do it?

Comment: @ErcanOzturk Actually perhaps no, since `java.lang.reflect.Array` does not implement these interfaces, and the statement in your question would thus be untrue for that bit.

Comment: Then how can I use this subtype relationship? Are we just saying there "is" a subtype relationship?

Comment: @ErcanOzturk No. Your original post gave a false assumption in the beginning in the quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is causing your confusion is that "cloneable" and "serializable" are attributes in the English language, and the phrase "is `Cloneable`" is commonly used to express that a class implements the `Cloneable` interface. However, here they *only* denote exactly the interface names `Cloneable` and `Serializable`, and "is" is to be understood as "is *exactly*/equals". That is, if `T` IS the interface `Cloneable` or if `T` IS the interface `Serializable`, then any array type is a subtype of `T`.

An `array type` is any type of the form `U[]`, where `U` is an arbitrary type, i.e., non-`void` primitive or reference type (note that an array type, even of a primitive type, also is a reference type). This has nothing to with the class `java.lang.reflect.Array`, which is **not** an array type!

You cannot assign any array to a reference variable of a class implementing `Cloneable` or `Serializable`, but only to a reference variable of *exactly* the type `Cloneable` or `Serializable`. Hence, if you have

```
int[] a = ...; // primitive array
Object[] b = ...; // reference type array
int[][] c = ...; // reference type array, since int[] is a reference type
```

then the following is legal:

```
Cloneable x = a; x = b; x = c;
Serializable y = a; y = b; y = c;
```